# How can I pass a long data parameter to django HttpResponseRedirect without it being truncated

Tags: python, django

I have a redirect URL with a parameter like ?data= which could be a very long string, and it's getting truncated by the redirect. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: URLs have length limits and your code might not work on all browsers. If you have large data, try passing it in a POST instead of as part of the URL.

Comment: If it's your own site you are redirecting to, a common solution is to store the data in a temporary location (e.g. session) under a unique key (e.g. random hash), and redirect to the destination with this unique key as argument. Then you can pluck the data from the session, and process as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using session variables:

```
request.session['blah'] = 1
request.session.get('blah')
```